# How to add/edit functionality in the same page without flickering?

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery, ajax, asp.net-ajax

My current asp.net(c#) project required   add/edit functionality in the same page without flickering.

To fill the textbox,fileuploader & dropdown list etc while updating the contents.

I searched google,but fileuploader not working properly in the ajax update panel

Please give examples/reference for solving the problem.

Answer (score 6):

The following links will help you.

http://www.ajaxlines.com/ajax/stuff/article/using_jquery_to_directly_call_aspnet_ajax_page_methods.php

http://encosia.com/2008/05/29/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/